# Deleting Parse.File from Cloud Code

Tags: google-app-engine, parse-platform, cloud

The objective is to delete Parse.File from Cloud Code using the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    method: 'DELETE',
    url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/' + file.name(),
    headers: {
        "X-Parse-Application-Id": "...",
        "X-Parse-Master-Key" : "..."
    },
    success: function(httpResponse) { // ... },
    error: function(httpResponse) { // ... }
});
```

How to get X-Parse-Master-Key" in Cloud Code?  As long as Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey () does not work in Parse.Cloud.httpRequest. it can't be used.

And it would be also great to obtain "X-Parse-Application-Id" in the Run Time, since we use the same Cloud Code in all our games.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `ParseMasterKey` on the settings page of your parse apps, so there's no way to get that from anywhere else unless you store it locally beforehand.

Not sure what you want with the `App-Id`, as its mostly the same as the `ParseMasterKey` (you can't get it via a request)

https://www.parse.com/questions/obtain-application-information-app-id-client-key-rest-key-programmatically